# Can in PhpStorm insert code which is in clipboard commented?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Can I in PhpStorm 2023.2.2 by selecting hot key inside editor to insert code
which is in clipboard commented? The result would be something like :

```php
/*
Text from clipboard
*/
```

I did not find where enter expression ?

[image]

?

Comment: It should be possible with Live Templates variables. Set a variable expression to "clipboard()".

Comment: I updated topic. Please check

Comment: @mstdmstd Insert the variable first (where you want that clipboard content to be inserted) and then use the `Edit Variables` button where you can use the actual `clipboard()` function. 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-live-templates.html 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tutorial-creating-live-templates.html 3) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/template-variables.html#predefined_functions

Comment: @LazyOne , I see "Edit Variables" - (on my printscreen) - but it is disabled.  b) Where have I to Insert the variable ?

Comment: @mstdmstd 1) Check the links that I've provided in my previous comment. Those are links to the official PhpStorm help / documentation page (I know, I know --  nobody wants to read the help/documentation these days, it's so boring and so 2023...) But it has ALL the info you need. 2) The button will become active once you have at leats one variable in your template.